# Also log every exception at error level

Tags: exception, grails, log4j

Using Groovy / Grails and log4j is there any way to ensure every exception thrown in the code is logged at error level.

Rather than having to find every catch block and explictly log it?

If not groovy / grails - a java suggestion will suffice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to do this for handled exceptions, but you can do it for unhandled exceptions by adding the following to `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"500"(controller: 'error')
```

Then create an `ErrorController.groovy` under `grails-app/controllers`

```
class ErrorController {

    def index() {
        Throwable exception = request?.exception?.cause 
        log.error 'something bad happened', exception
    }
}
```